# Bootstrap scroll-down when the user clicks the button

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How to use the page-scroll down like [in this example](http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-agency/) without any connection using a nav bar, especially on the JavaScript part?

What I want to happen is like in the example: once the user click the button it will directly go to the section page and it should be smooth scrolling same as with the sample link.

Here's my sample code

```
<div class="jumbotron">

<div class="career-jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#opportunities" class="page-scroll btn btn-xl">
         Button</a>
    </div>
</div> 
<section id="opportunities">
    <div class="container">

    -----sample text-----

    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried something yet? If you have your code, would you be able to share it with us? Then, somebody will be able to help you. :)

Comment: here's the sample code

Answer (score 0):

Here is a javascript snippet to get a smooth scrolling *same page links*, it watches and apply the smooth effect to all links starting with `#`

**You need to add jQuery library**

```
 $(function(){
   $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
       if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
         var target = $(this.hash);
         target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
         if (target.length) {
           $('html,body').animate({
             scrollTop: (target.offset().top - 135) // adjust this according to your content
           }, 1000);
           return false;
         }
       }
   });
 });
```

Comment: MS Edge writes: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#]:not([href=#])

Answer (score 0):

One way that worked for me without using JS...

```
<div class="jumbotron">

<div class="career-jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
        <button type="button" class="btn"><a href="#opputunities" style="text-decoration: none; color: black">Button</a></button>
    </div>
</div> 
<section id="opportunities">
    <div class="container">

    -----sample text-----

    </div>
</section>
```